# How to get value for key in array when the key is not known

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a $_POST request in which my values are coming like,

```
Array
(
    [name] => hello
    [category] => world
)
```

This i am sending it in a method `search_data($_POST)`.

But when i do $_POST['$name'] it says,

> undefined offset $name

How do I get the value in the array when the key is not defined in the code and is coming in a post request.

Comment: According to the notice that can't be your real code. Don't you have something like `$_POST['$name']`? Whatever, I don't really understand the question. I think you're missing relevant code.

Comment: or do like this :  echo $this->input->post('name'); without using $_POST

Comment: `$name` => `name`.  It isn't a var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this without `$_POST` as ;

```
function search_data()
{
   echo $this->input->post('name'); 
   echo $this->input->post('category'); 
}
```

Or use something like this if you are passing `$_POST` to the method;

```
function search_data($_POST)
{
   echo $_POST['name'];
   echo $_POST['category'];
}
```

Comment: some one is very unhappy with my answer that is why he downvotes my answer thanks for down-voting, do keep like this, frustrated fellow